# How combine Dagger2 and coroutines?

Tags: android, dagger, kotlin-coroutines

I'am using `dagger2` + `retrofit` + `coroutines` + `firebaseRemoteConfig`

I can't get `totoName` updated every time I change the remote configs in the Firebase console. The problem is my use of coroutines... can you help me? Thanks

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("toto")
    suspend fun provideToto(remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig): String {
        var totoName  = fetchToto(remoteConfig)
        return totoName
    }

    suspend fun fetchToto(remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig): String {
        var totoName = remoteConfig.getString("toto_name")

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                totoName  = remoteConfig.getString("toto_name")
            }
        }
        return totoName
    }
```

Comment: it seems that suspend and @Provides are not compatible  https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1502

Comment: kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking and javax.inject.Provider or dagger.Lazy

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that Dagger itself is configured to work with suspensions. Dagger works in pass. First, it asks for the object, if the object isn't ready it ask for object creation. There isn't any inbuilt functionality for awaiting for the suspension to complete. Moreover, dagger objects are lazy initialized Singletons hence you only get what you create. So you already saving memory. Plus firebase is initialized at the application level (preloaded). So you always get ready to use firebase instances. So no need to suspend for creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So you advise me to initialize firebase at the Application level ?

Comment: @ZachBvy Firebase SDK does that automatically for you, manual initializing is optional, also `addOnCompleteListener` is a member function of `Task` object they are already async, It won't block the main thread. You don't need any suspension here.

Comment: yes but in fact my problem concerns rather retrofit... because I pass it a url retrieved from firebase custom config. And I'm annoyed because I don't have time to get the new value of the url since firebase.

Comment: See. If your first dependency is of firebase network call then you can do two things . 1. Make network call from your application class(I will highly discourage this but it's necessary for your case) 2. Try to put some animation at startup of your app so user doesn't get to know you are doing a long running network task.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that doesn't work. First of all if you use `@Singleton` there fill be only one `fetch()` for the entire app.

Next, I'm not really sure you may do that with dagger at all. Your methods should be located in the respective classes and not on some dependency graph.